# How concatenation operator and concat() performs any task

Tags: java

I can use either concatenation operator`(+)` or `concat()` method for string concatenation

```
String myData = "a"+"b";            // using concatenation operator
String myData = "a".concat("b");    // using concat() of String
```

But to concate a string with integer I cannot use concat() directly. SO I have to use either of the following logic

```
String myData = "a"+5;
String myData = "a".concat(String.valueOf(5));
```

But I found some thing strange in the following line when I want to use concatenation operator and concat

```
String myData = "a"+null;              //output =  anull
    String myData = "a".concat(String.valueOf(5)); // output = NullPointerException
or
    String myData = "a".concat(null); // output = NullPointerException
```

I have below question arised in my mind

```
1) How concat() method and concatenation operator works what is the difference in their logic of performing any task?
2) Can we really concat a null using (+) if so why concat() method cannot achieve the same
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The `+` operator (to produce `String`s) always goes through an intermediate `StringBuilder` (or `StringBuffer` if targeting old platforms before 1.5 (released 7 (seven) years ago)). For concatenating two or perhaps three `String`s `concat` will generally be faster due to the lack of intermediate. However, for longer concatenations `+` will win because there will be fewer intermediate allocations.

2) `null` generally indicates an error (quite possibly a design error). In general, errors should be reported as early as possible, which `String.concat` does. However, `+` or `StringBuilder` concatenation is often used to produce debug strings, so the `null` is tolerated and produces a result suitable for debugging (but not UI!).

Comment: thanks for your reply but my doubt is little bit different .what is the internal process of working of these two. because if i think about two operand only then first option gives result while second is not. if it is so then ho first one is able to produce result. does it really concat a string with a null

Comment: `String myData = "a"+null` is transformed by javac into something like `StringBuilder $buff = new StringBuilder(); $buff.append("a"); $buff.append(null); String myData = $buff.toString();`. Inside `StringBuilder.append` (and you can look through the source in `src.zip` inside the JDK), it just checks for `null` and if found appends the string `"null"`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference in the semantics, you just got your example wrong.

```
String myData = "a"+null;              //output =  anull

String myData = "a".concat(String.valueOf( (Object)null ) ); // output = anull
```

And this will compile and work. `+` behaves as if `String.valueOf()` was invoked for every operand.